# Need to select row_number which is last

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, row-number

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
AnimalName  AnimalType  RowNumber   
---------------------------------------------------------------
Chicken         Bird        1   
Duck            Bird        2       
Alpaca          Mammal      1   
Camel           Mammal      2   
Carabao         Mammal      3   
Whale           Sea         1   
Shark           sea         2   
Prawns          Sea         3   
Eel             sea         4
```

**OUTPUT**

```
AnimalName      AnimalType  RowNumber   
------------------------------------------------------------        
Duck              Bird          2   
Carabao           Mammal        3   
Eel               sea           4
```

Query:

```
  SELECT t.* from (
select  
    AnimalName,
    AnimalType,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AnimalType ORDER BY AnimalName) AS RowNumber
FROM    Animal A
) t
where rownumber=1
```

Above query is giving me all the 1st rownumber, If i want to select the last rownumber then what changes i have to make.
for eg: bird max rownumber is 2, mammal max is 3 and sea max is 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `DESC` instead of `ASC` for the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM (SELECT AnimalName, AnimalType,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AnimalType ORDER BY AnimalName DESC) AS RowNumber
      FROM Animal a
     ) a
WHERE rownumber = 1;
```

If you really want to keep the row numbers, the same, then use `COUNT(*)` for the comparison:

```
SELECT a.AnimalName, a.AnimalType, a.rownumber
FROM (SELECT AnimalName, AnimalType,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AnimalType ORDER BY AnimalName) AS RowNumber,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY AnimalType) as cnt
      FROM Animal a
     ) a
WHERE rownumber = cnt;
```